# Find the JTable cell and paint it

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, tablecellrenderer

I have these data:

1. Row Number
2. Column Number
3. Cell Value

My questions are:

1. How can I find the cell by using those data?
2. How can I change the background of `JTable` cell on mouse press event and back to normal background on mouse release Event?
3. Can i Highlight the JTable without user interaction, means clicking on some other JTable cell i want to highlight another JTable cell by using given information, is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean to find the rectangle of the cell for hit detection:

```
 Rectangle cell = table.getCellRect(row, column, false);
```

For background changing, in your mouseListener code, set a marker which cell was hit, repaint on pressed/released and implement a custom renderer which checks for the marker. Some pseudo-code

```
 void mousePressed(MouseEvent ev) {
     // get the row/column from mouse location
     int column = table.columnAtPoint(ev.getPoint());
     int row = table.rowAtPoint(ev.getPoint());
     // set some kind of marker, f.i. as client property
     table.putClientProperty("hitColumn", column);
     table.putClientProperty("hitRow", row);
     // get the rectangle for repainting 
     Rectangle cell = table.getCellRect(column, row, false);
     table.repaint(cell);
 }

 void mouseReleased(MouseEvent ev) {
     // similar to reset the marker
     ....
     table.repaint(cell);
 }

 // custom renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer

 JComponent getTableCellRendererComponent(..., row, column ...) {
     Integer hitColumn = table.getClientProperty("hitColumn");
     Integer hitRow = ....
     if (hitColumn != null && column == hitColumn && hitRow ....) {
        setBackground(hitColor);
     } else {
         // force super to handle the background 
         setBackground(null);
     }
     return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(....);
 }
```

Comment: Can i do the same without user interaction of that particular table means on clicking of something else?

Comment: sure - clientProperties are ... just properties: listen to changes of those in the first and do with the value whatever you want to :-)