# Highlight Rectangle Object

Tags: java, swing, jtable, graphic, tablecellrenderer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the JTable cell and paint it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236168/find-the-jtable-cell-and-paint-it)

This is my Rectangle class object.

```
 Rectangle cell = table.getCellRect(row, column, false);
```

Now I want to highlight it on mouse press event and again back to normal to mouse realeased event.

Comment: I'm not able to see any difference betweens your last question, yes is possible (`Can i do the same without user interaction of that particular table means on clicking of something else?`), this is basic properties of XxxCellRenderer, no idea where your question goes

Comment: *"I want.."*  a question, and no.  Adding a '?' to the end of a specification or instruction, does not make it a question.  What is your question?

Comment: @mKorbel Thanks for your guidence, will follow that surely.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for your attention.I have done the required changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to add the feature.

The first one is implementing custom Renderer/Editor for the cell. The renderer keeps row/column and isPressed state. When mouse is pressed renderer state is set and reset on release.

Another way is to override `JTable's` paintComponent() method to draw the `Rectangle` with e.g. semi-transparent color.

Comment: Or use SwingX's highligher API

Comment: nitpicking again: the renderer mustn't _keep_ state - it queries the state and temporarily (per-cell) configures itself accordingly. You and me know that, newbies might not yet :-) Plus, paintComponent in a table is extremely rarely tweaked.